# Differences between objective function definitions in optimization problems

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, error-function

Can someone explain the differences between the relative error definitions used as an objective function in a constrained optimization problem? I am trying to understand why I get different values of $\rho \in \mathbb{R}^{3}$ using `fmincon` in MATLAB.

The first is normalized by the sum of the two complex valued functions $Z(\omega),\hat{Z}(\rho,\omega) \in \mathbb{C}$
\begin{equation}
\underset{\rho}{\text{arg min}}\quad
\frac{\left\lVert Z(\omega) - \hat{Z}(\rho,\omega)\right\rVert^{2}}{\left\lVert Z(\omega) + \hat{Z}(\rho,\omega) \right\rVert^{2}},
\end{equation}
while the second is normalized by only one of them
\begin{equation}
\underset{\rho}{\text{arg min}}\quad
\frac{\left\lVert Z(\omega) - \hat{Z}(\rho,\omega) \right\rVert^{2}}{\left\lVert Z(\omega) \right\rVert^{2}},
\end{equation}
where $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert^{2}$ is the $L^{2}$-norm over frequency $\omega$.

Does this have something to do with the complex functions $Z(\omega),\hat{Z}(\rho,\omega) \in \mathbb{C}$ inside the norm?